Did Haru and Tokaku really kiss?
In EP7, when Haru goes underwater to save Tokaku from drowning and not exploding (Tokaku was in a human cage bomb underwater). Even though Tokaku wants Haru to save herself by taking the card key, Haru puts her lips against Tokaku, which awakens Tokaku.
So was that a life-saving thing or a legit kiss?


What's the difference?

Well, a kiss is special while a life-saving kiss is where you have to give them oxygen quickly. The life-saving kiss is more like CPR, which counts not as a true kiss. A true kiss is wonderful, not that I've ever kissed anyone. So, I suppose that is the difference.
